# Open opportunities owned on user profile/overview page?

Tags: chatter, opportunity, user

Looking for a solution to add a user's opportunities on their personal profile/overview page -

Currently you can follow this flow to navigate to your personal profile page:
Click your name > My Profile > Click "Overview" > You can then view the "About Me" section, Chatter Files Owned, and Chatter Group Membership of the user.

With this same UI could we add a visualforce section that includes that user's "Open Opportunites"? We are just looking to find this information at a glance on the user's profile page rather than navigating to create a report or review an opportunity list view.

Any experience with a custom solution for this use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the profile subtabs feature to add a VisualForce tab for "Open Opportunities" that shows up beside "Overview" on your user profile page. See here for more info:

http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2014/01/extending-chatter-profile-with-custom.html

Comment: From Salesforce documents http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_subtab_manage.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's a way you can add VF pages to that particular page. One option, which admittedly isn't great, would be to create a VF page that wraps that particular page in an iframe and then displays the opportunities underneath the frame. You could create a VF tab for that page to make it easily accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Matt. So basically on the VF page I just need to call out logic to pull a specific user on the UI. We need the ability for a user to review their own opps on this type of page and/or the ability to review another rep's open opps by going to their "profile page" (or mimics it with a VF page).

Comment: Do you know about profile subtabs? http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2014/01/extending-chatter-profile-with-custom.html

Comment: @alouie, I did not, and those look awesome! Write up an answer using those and Girod should be able to accept it instead.

Answer (score 0):

We have a great solution in place now utilizing the sub-tabs.

The feedback was greatly appreciated all!